Helix vscode-langservers-extracted not working
I have a project that's using eslint, but when I open it in Helix, the linting does not work.

Helix 24.7 doesn't seem to be working with the latest version of vscode-langservers-extracted, simply installing a previous version (4.9.0) of vscode-langservers-extracted solved the problem for me.
Installation: npm i -g vscode-langservers-extracted@4.9.0
